# How do you run migrations for a particular gem on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

On development environment I have build a new `gem` and installed it running `bundle exec rails g new_gem_name:install` which installs the `gem`'s migrations

After pushing it to heroku I need to do the same thing there.

How to I run only this gem's migrations on heroku ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the same command using heroku-cli:

`heroku run rails g new_gem_name:install`

If you don't have it installed locally then here are instructions on how to do it: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

Comment: Is it important to include the `bundle exec` portion, i.e. `heroku run bundle exec rails g new_gem_name:install`?

Comment: You may use it, but on heroku only gems from your Gemfile are installed therefore there are no extraneous gems that might cause an issue, so `bundle exec` can be omitted on heroku